# How to control Select / Options in Django Forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Using Django I aim to create a form with a "select" field, and populate that with values from the db table "TestTable".

TestTable's fields are: id, desc1, desck2, desc3, desc4, etc...

Here is my code in the form.py:

```
class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    field1 = ModelChoiceField(queryset=TestTable.objects.all().order_by('desc1'))
    class Meta(object):
        model = BlockValue
        fields = ()
```

Here is the template:

```
<html>
<head><title>TEST PAGE</title></head>

<body>
Test: 
{{ form }} 

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the view.py:

```
def test(request):
    form = TestForm()
    return render(request, 'test.html', {'form': form})
```

When I render the form the result is:

```
<tr><th><label for="id_field1">Field1:</label></th><td><select id="id_field1" name="field1">
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
<option value="1">aaaaaaa</option>
<option value="3">bbbbbbb</option>
<option value="2">ccccccc</option>
</select></td></tr>
```

How to chose which field print in the option tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways. The quick way to is to change the `__unicode__` return for your `TestTable` to return the field you like. However you might only want to show that field in current form but not other places, so it's not ideal.

Second option, you could define you own form field. It inherits `ModelChoiceField`, but override `label_from_instance` method:

```
class TestTableModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
         # return the field you want to display
         return obj.display_field

class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    type = TestTableModelChoiceField(queryset=Property.objects.all().order_by('desc1'))
```

Comment: Thanks. It is totally working. Are there any possibility to set the `<option value="TestTable.id">` as well?

Comment: I thought it's already doing that and that's the default setup. Can you double check the page source on each `<option>`?

Answer (score 1):

```
class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) # initialize form, which will create self.fields dict
        self.fields['field1'].choices = [(o.id, str(o).upper()) for o in TestTable.objects.all()] # provide a list of tuples [(pk,display_string),(another_pk,display_str),...]
        # display string can be whatever str/unicode you want to show.
```